# Xcode 7 build failed due to ld: library not found for -liPhone-lib

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, arkit

I'm trying to build my first ARKit app with Xcode 9 beta for iOS 11.

When I build my application on Xcode, I get the following error

"Xcode 7 build failed due to ld: library not found for -liPhone-lib

error: linker command failed with exit code 1"

Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess its Unity3D game. I also observed linker error for liPhone-lib. 
Solution is simple, just drag liPhone-lib's parent folder to library search path. 
Clean Build. Cheers

In my project, liPhone-lib placed in Libraries folder. So I just dragged Libraries folder to Xcode library search path...its solved my problem.

See attach image:[image]

Comment: I'm a complete newb - where is the Xcode library search path or how do I get there?

Thanks!

Comment: @YoniBinstock I added screenshot that shows dragging folder to Xcode library search path

Answer (score 0):

Looks like either Unity or Xcode incorrectly puts double quotes around the search path for the Libraries folder.

1. In Xcode, click your target and open Build Settings
2. Find Library Search Paths and remove all the escaped double quotes,

In the project's Library Search Paths, find the entry that looks like this:

```
\"$(SRCROOT)/Libraries\"
```

double click the entry to edit it and remove the escaped double quotes, so it looks like this:

```
$(SRCROOT)/Libraries
```

The project should now compile correctly again.